# maven jetty does not shutdown properly in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently running jetty from eclipse as an external java program. The problem is when I terminate jetty and I try to relaunch it again, it cannot due to the port still being in use.

What I have to do is open up Windows Task Manager and kill the java process manually. How do you get jetty to shutdown/terminate/end nicely?

The following are my maven jetty application settings

> Arguments: jetty:run-war
>
> MAVEN_OPTS: -Xdebug -Xnoagent
>   -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket, address=8080,server=y, suspend=y

Setting suspend=n doesn't seem to solve the problem either.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, stop() method is not killing the Jetty process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I forgot to tick "Allow termination of remote VM". Strange that it didn't seem to work before.

Answer (score 1):

If a java application does not shutdown it is because of an alive non-daemon thread. Try getting a thread dump of the running maven process, e.g. using [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) and see what keeps the application alive.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the application via the 'Run Jetty Run' Eclipse plugin, rather than the Maven jetty plugin.  Eclipse has more direct control over the new JVM then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the maven plug-in, but when starting jetty with start.jar, you can use stop.jar to have it shutdown gracefully (since version 4.something).

```
Stopping Jetty

Programs started with the start.jar mechanism may be stopped with the
stop.jar:


   java -jar stop.jar


This connects via a local port to stop the server. The default port can be set
 with the STOP.PORT system property
```

[Source](http://jetty.mortbay.org/jetty5/tut/GettingStarted.html)

Alternatively, and maybe more to your liking, you can do it within eclipse by writing a class like this, and running the main method:

```
   package mypackage;  

   import java.io.OutputStream;  
   import java.net.InetAddress;  
   import java.net.Socket;  

   public class Stop {  
       public static final int PORT = 8079; //Change to whatever your port is, 8079 is default

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
          Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), PORT);  
          OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();  
          System.out.println("*** sending jetty stop request");  
          out.write(("\r\n").getBytes());  
          out.flush();  
          s.close();  
      }  

  }
```

[Source](http://ptrthomas.wordpress.com/2009/01/24/how-to-start-and-stop-jetty-revisited/)